# What's the difference between LayoutInflater's Factory and Factory2

Tags: java, android, layout-inflater

There is two public interfaces:

[`LayoutInflater.Factory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.Factory.html) and [`LayoutInflater.Factory2`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.Factory2.html) in android sdk, but official documentation can't say something helpfull about this interfaces, even [`LayoutInflater`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) documentation.

From sources I've understood that if `Factory2` was set then it will be used and `Factory` otherwise:

```
View view;
if (mFactory2 != null) {
    view = mFactory2.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
} else if (mFactory != null) {
    view = mFactory.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
} else {
    view = null;
}
```

`setFactory2()` also have very laconic documentation:

```
/**
 * Like {@link #setFactory}, but allows you to set a {@link Factory2}
 * interface.
 */
public void setFactory2(Factory2 factory) {
```

Which factory should I use If I want to set custom factory to `LayoutInflater`?
And what is the difference of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difference is that in `Factory2` you can configure who's the new view's `parent view` will be.

**Usage -**
Use `Factory2` when you need to set specific parent to the new view your 
creating.(Support API 11 and above only)

**Code - LayoutInflater source:**(after removing irrelevant code)

```
public interface Factory {
         // @return View Newly created view. 
        public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs);
    }
```

Now `Factory2`:

```
public interface Factory2 extends Factory {
         // @param parent The parent that the created view will be placed in.
         // @return View Newly created view. 
        public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs);
    }
```

Now you can see that `Factory2` is just overload of `Factory` with the `View parent` option.

Answer (score 3):

> Which factory should I use If I want to set custom factory to
>   LayoutInflater? And what is the difference of them?

If you need to supply the parent that the view created will be placed in, you want to use `Factory2`. But generally use `Factory2` if your targeting API level 11+. Otherwise, just use `Factory`.

Here is `Factory`

```
class MyLayoutInflaterFactory implements LayoutInflater.Factory {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (TextUtils.equals(name, "MyCustomLayout")) {
            return new MyCustomLayout(context, attrs);
        }
        // and so on...
        return super.onCreateView(name, context attrs);
    }
}
```

Here is `Factory2`

```
class MyLayoutInflaterFactory2 implements LayoutInflater.Factory2 {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (TextUtils.equals(name, "MyCustomLayout")) {
            return new MyCustomLayout(context, attrs);
        }
        // and so on...
        return super.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
    }
}
```